# IntelliJ - Disable Collapsed Blocks from Opening on Refactor

Tags: intellij-idea

Comment a large block in IntelliJ then collapse it.

Refactor some other code on the same page, and the block will open, even if it was not affected by the refactor.

How can I disable collapsed blocks from opening on refactor?